# How To Install Xcache on CentOS 6 and Nginx?

Tags: centos, nginx, centos6, php-fpm, xcache

I've bought a new VPS and I'm not a linux geek. I've already installed LEMP stack on CentOS 6. I just tried to install Xcache on my VPS. I've used the below command to install Xcache but it shows an error.

Command I used to install Xcache

```
yum install php-xcache xcache-admin
```

And the error I've got:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.san.fastserv.com
 * epel: mirrors.kernel.org
 * extras: mirror.pac-12.org
 * updates: mirrors.easynews.com
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-xcache.x86_64 0:3.0.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20090626 for package: php-xcache-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20090626 for package: php-xcache-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64
---> Package xcache-admin.noarch 0:3.0.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: mod_php for package: xcache-admin-3.0.2-1.el6.noarch
--> Processing Dependency: httpd for package: xcache-admin-3.0.2-1.el6.noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package httpd.x86_64 0:2.2.15-29.el6.centos will be installed
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.3.3-23.el6_4 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-23.el6_4 for package: php-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-cli(x86-64) = 5.3.3-23.el6_4 for package: php-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64
---> Package php-xcache.x86_64 0:3.0.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20090626 for package: php-xcache-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20090626 for package: php-xcache-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.3.3-23.el6_4 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-23.el6_4 for package: php-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64
---> Package php-cli.x86_64 0:5.3.3-23.el6_4 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-23.el6_4 for package: php-cli-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64
---> Package php-xcache.x86_64 0:3.0.2-1.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php(zend-abi) = 20090626 for package: php-xcache-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php(api) = 20090626 for package: php-xcache-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-xcache-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: php(api) = 20090626
           Installed: php-common-5.4.17-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php(api) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
               php(api) = 20090626
Error: Package: php-xcache-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Installed: php-common-5.4.17-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               php(zend-abi) = 20100525-x86-64
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php(zend-abi) = 20090626
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
               php(zend-abi) = 20090626
Error: Package: php-cli-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-23.el6_4
           Installed: php-common-5.4.17-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.17-2.el6.remi
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-22.el6
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-23.el6_4
Error: Package: php-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-23.el6_4
           Installed: php-common-5.4.17-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.17-2.el6.remi
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-22.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-22.el6
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-23.el6_4.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-23.el6_4
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Please help me how to install the Xcache on my VPS.

Answer (score 2):

I think the error message is pretty clear:

```
Error: Package: php-xcache-3.0.2-1.el6.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: php(api) = 20090626
           Installed: php-common-5.4.17-2.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               php(api) = 20100412-x86-64
```

Since you have used the Remi repository to install [php-5.4.17-2.el6.remi.x86_64](http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/remi/x86_64/repoview/php.html), you should be installing his [php-xcache-3.0.3-1.el6.remi.x86_64](http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/remi/x86_64/repoview/php-xcache.html) package, and not EPEL's, which, as the error message explains, depends on a lower PHP version.

Comment: Will you please tell me what to do now? How to install this REMI package?

Comment: How did you install the PHP package in the first place?

Comment: @Daman If this answer helped you solve the problem, please mark it as solved by clicking the check mark next to it. Otherwise please post your own answer and let the world know what you did.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Solved**

*My Problem*: I was getting an error while configuring my new VPS. I found that I was trying to install Xcache using EPEL's repo on my VPS. I now installed Xcache using RPM's repository. The whole problem was caused because I had used RPM's repository to install [php-5.4.17-2.el6.remi.x86_64](http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/remi/x86_64/repoview/php.html). Since I used RPM's repo to install php, I need to do the same to install the Xcache.

Below the code that I used to install Xcache in My CentOS powered VPS

```
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/remi/x86_64/php-xcache-3.0.3-1.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm
```

I got the following response from the command line:

```
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]   
1:php-xcache-3.0.3-1.el6.remi.x86_64    ########################################### [100%]
```

Finally, It is working now..